# Review possible improvement

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For reviewing I always try to leave a comment if there needs to be improvement, expansion, etc. I have been reviewing a lot of vague (new) posts recently. I do not want to downvote a potentially "good" question/answer, because the poster is new.

I don't want to flag as "un-salvageable", because it could be edited if they post more information, but in current state is vague.

I am unsure whether I should downvote and comment now, then check in on the post every week. This would be very time intensive as more reviews pile in, and not practical. Or allow the post to go through with a comment at the bottom to improve the question/answer.

I don't want the quality of the site to go down, but I don't want to penalize someone on their first attempt either.

If there could be a vague flag that put a question on hold (until improvement), with notification to the person flagging that would be great. At this moment my reputation doesn't allow me to participate in every privilege, but I was trying to think of something to improve on controlling question quality, even at lower levels of review.

Comment: Are you talking of something other than the "Unclear what you are asking" flag?